# image bytes upload with request parameter swift 4

Tags: swift4, ios11

URL = https://test...com/camimage.aspx

Method Type : Post

Request Parameter :

1. Header Parameter [“UserID”]
2. Image Bytes

I got only above info with url and post request in multipart form data. I tried with swift4 multipart but not able to achieve the expected result.

**Updated Question with Code and Log**

```
 func UploadRequest()
{
    let url = URL(string: "https://...com/webcam/camimage.aspx")

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"


    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.addValue("UserID", forHTTPHeaderField: "110159")
    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    if (imageView.image == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let image_data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageView.image!)

    if(image_data == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    let body = NSMutableData()
    let fname = "test.png"
    let mimetype = "image/png"


    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Disposition:form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\"; filename=\"\(fname)\"\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
    body.append(image_data!)
    body.append("\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!)

    request.httpBody = body as Data

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
        (
        data, response, error) in

        guard ((data) != nil), let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        if let dataString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        {
            print(dataString)
        }

    })

    task.resume()

}


func generateBoundaryString() -> String
{
    return "*****"
}
```

I am putting Android Code also. It may help to analysis

```
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(SERVER_URL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);
            connection.setRequestProperty("UserID", "110159");
            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }

            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        tvFileName.setText("File Upload completed.\n\n You can see the uploaded file here: \n\n" + "http://coderefer.com/extras/uploads/"+ fileName);
                    }
                });
            }

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();
```

I able to upload image via postman. Still not able to configured to upload via swift code.

Please check the attached two postman webapi chrome tool screenshots. Hope expert could help me out..

1st
[image]

2nd
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ask your server side engineer what is the right format. Images may be uploaded in various ways. Using whole HTTP body in binary, base64 or hex. May be JSON with encoded bytes in some encoding. Can be `multipart/form-data`, or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` might also be used. What format does your server use?

Comment: Yes it's a multipart/form-data. Getting internal server error 500.

Comment: Please show your code you used to send the `multipart/form-data` request and got server error 500. And please try to get the server log when you get that error.

Comment: @OOPer I have updated question with code and Xcode log. Need to know the missing element in coding. Thank you.

Comment: Your ERROR LOG is the default 500 page of your server and has no info about the server error. Please try to get the server side log. And as far as I checked your way of creating body seems to be correct (though, your code seems too old, better avoid using NS-classes), but you should better check a few things. You are sending two parameters `test` and `file`, are those correct? If the server really accepts `multipart/form-data`, the parameter names must be specified, check the names with the API specification.

Comment: And why are you setting `UserID` twice? - `request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["UserID":"110159"]` and `request.addValue("UserID", forHTTPHeaderField: "110159")`. A single line `request.setValue("110159", forHTTPHeaderField: "UserID")` would work.

Comment: @OOper : I have uploaded screenshots of Postman tool. From this I am able to upload image and getting 200 Response. But not able to achieve result with Swift code. Can you help with the code...

Comment: I think your passing wrong parameter for image, in your code `name=\"file\"`. and in postman `uploaded_file`. so change `name=\"file\"` to `name=\"uploaded_file\"`

Comment: @NavnathMemane, you are not replying to my comments of Sep 15. Read the two comments carefully, in addition to the one of Pratik Prajapati's.

Comment: @PratikPrajapati I changed name=\"file\" to name=\"uploaded_file\" Same server error 500. AT : OOper : I have passed UserID one time as per your comment. Have removed that second line where USERID was resending... I guess the error causing because of UserID not properly passed in Header

Comment: @NavnathMemane, **_as per your comment_** Seems you have not yet read the comment **carefully**.

Comment: @OOPer I requested error log to client. So he sent me Android java code. It has multipart form code with keywords. Hope it help more analyze...

Comment: @NavnathMemane, that would be actually some help, as I suggested in one of my comments. But you may need to read another comment of mine **carefully**.I would like to spend much time for who reads comments carefully and responds to them...

Comment: I see no correlation between the Java and Swift code; the Swift code does a __completely different thing__ in fundamental, so there is no wonder of why it is not working like the Java snippet.

Comment: Actually I am not good at Java and doing multipart for the first time. I got multipart swift code from googling and tried to tweak.  At OOPer : Yes you said to avoid NS classes and regarding keywords to crosscheck(I tried as per Android keyword too). Server log didn't receive from backend  as he not available in last 15 days.

Comment: @holex : At OOper : Can you suggest sample for the above requirement by analyzing Java code.

Comment: @NavnathMemane, yes, sure, you need to check how to build up the _header_ and the _body_ again; don't mix their content arbitrarily on an ad-hoc way – I'm not even sure where the idea of the _Swift_ implementation has come from, that is very much distinct from the Java snippet, I would recommend you to delete your current _Swift_ implementation and start again from scratch, that may help you to understand the differences and resolve them nicely.

Comment: @NavnathMemane, do you really understand which comment I'm referring?

Answer (score 0):

use this pod : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Ref : https://gist.github.com/DejanEnspyra/5bae2a301b2b2bb5de3109344345617f

```
func requestWith(endUrl: String, imageData: Data?, parameters: [String : Any], onCompletion: ((JSON?) -> Void)? = nil, onError: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil){

let url = "http://google.com" /* your API url */

let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
    /* "Authorization": "your_access_token",  in case you need authorization header */
    "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
]

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
    for (key, value) in parameters {
        multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
    }

    if let data = imageData{
        multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }

}, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in
    switch result{
    case .success(let upload, _, _):
        upload.responseJSON { response in
            print("Succesfully uploaded")
            if let err = response.error{
                onError?(err)
                return
            }
            onCompletion?(nil)
        }
    case .failure(let error):
        print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        onError?(error)
    }
}
}
```